# MetaMask, what is it and how to use it

Tags: contract-development, metamask

I am relatively new to the eth community and i am currently trying to find a good way of using eth blockchain to create a signuo/signin mechanism. it turns out to do so in browsers, something like Metamask is needed.

What is Metamask ? what does it do ?

**EDIT**

What i need to know is what exactly should i do when having to use the users eth address to authenticate him/her ? in my recent attempts i had to use a login box like this one :

[image]

Of course i do have code behind that verifies the address and the login infos, but with metamsk i still don't grasp what should i do.

Comment: This is a bit broad and open-ended. Is there something specific you don't understand after reviewing the content on metamask.io?

Comment: @smarx, i did see the video from metamask.io. i did also an edit, please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to incorporate an authentication system into your app, using the blockchain, you could use something like Uport.

https://www.uport.me/